# Combine multiple Pandas series with identical column names, but different indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many pandas series structured more or less as follows.

```
s1                  s2                  s3                 s4
Date    val1        Date    val1        Date   val2        Date    val2
Jan     10          Apr     25          Jan    14          Apr     11
Feb     11          May     18          Feb    17          May     7
Mar     8           Jun     15          Mar    16          Jun     21
```

I would like to combine these series into a single data frame, with structure as follows:

```
Date    val1    val2
Jan     10      14
Feb     11      17
Mar     8       16
Apr     25      11
May     18      7
Jun     15      21
```

In an attempt to combine them, I have tried using `pd.concat` to create this single data frame. However, I have not been able to do so. The results of `pd.concat(series, axis=1)` (where `series` is a list `[s1,s2,s3,s4]`) is:

```
Date    val1    val1    val2    val2
Jan     10      nan     14      nan
Feb     11      nan     17      nan
Mar     8       nan     16      nan
Apr     nan     25      nan     11
May     nan     18      nan     7
Jun     nan     15      nan     21
```

And `pd.concat(series, axis=0)` simply creates a single series, ignoring the column names.

Is there a parameter in concat that will yield my desired result? Or is there some other function that can collapse the incorrect, nan-filled data frame into a frame with non-repeated columns and no nans?

Comment: your input looks like a multiindexed dataframe btw

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do is groupby `Date` and choose `first`:

```
(pd.concat( [s1,s2,s3,s4])
   .groupby('Date', as_index=False, sort=False).first()
)
```

Output:

```
  Date  val1  val2
0  Jan    10    14
1  Feb    11    17
2  Mar     8    16
3  Apr    25    11
4  May    18     7
5  Jun    15    21
```